# Find files which share part of a filename

Tags: bash, match

In my current directory there are many files. Some of the files share part of their filename.

e.g.:

```
XGAE_537493_GSR.FITS
TGFE_537493_RRF.FITS
EGRE_537497_HDR.FITS
TRTE_537497_YUH.FITS
TRXX_537499_YDF.FITS    
.
.
```

Files 1 & 2 would be a match, as would files 3 & 4. File 5 has no match. Therefore, files 1,2,3 and 4 would be moved.

I want to move the files which share part of their filename, in order to separate them from the ones that don't.

I was attempting to do this using bash. I googled but couldn't locate websites that were quite describing the process I need. So far in pseudo-code I have:

```
FOR F IN *
IF ${FILE:5:10} MATCHES ANY OTHER ${FILE:5:10}
MOVE ALL MATCHES TO ANOTHER DIRECTORY
```

Any information to help me move in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't say how the file names match.  Could you add that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for f in ./*.FITS ; do
    middleBit=$(echo $f| cut -d'_' -f 1)
    count=$(ls *middleBit*.FITS | wc -l)
    if [ $count -ge 1 ]
    then
       for match in *middleBit*.FITS ; do
           mv $match ./somewhere
       done
    fi
done
```

Comment: But there are many "common bits" so I would have to do this multiple times manually. I have added to my question now to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Is it only the central number that you wish to match?  Or also the letters?

Comment: Yeah just the numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if your file structure is fixed, you can scan them and find duplicates in sub fields of the file name in awk.

for example

```
$ ls -1 | awk -F_ 'NF==3{f[$2]=(a[$2]++?f[$2] OFS $0:$0)}
                     END{for(k in f) if(a[k]>1) print f[k]} '

TGFE_537493_RRF.FITS
XGAE_537493_GSR.FITS
```

you can then pipe the results to a cp command

```
$ ... | xargs -I file cp file file.DUP
```

adds suffix DUP to duplicate file names,  or

```
$ ... | xargs -I file mv file anotherlocation/
```

moves to anotherlocation.

Answer (score 1):

Using associative array in BASH 4 you can do it easily:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr

for f in *.FITS; do
    k="${f:5:6}"
    [[ ${arr[$k]} ]] && mv "$f" /dest/ || arr["$k"]=1
done
```